# Angular animation trigger on click

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

I have an angular animation that only needs to take place in the responsive view that has a button that triggers the animation, How can I approach this by only having this in the responsive and not the desktop? i I have the animation working, I just need to make sure when NOT mobile the animation doesn't get trigger, but still show the div, if responsive show with animation. (I don't have a button to trigger it in the desktop) it needs to show by default.

**ts**

```
animations: [
    trigger('slideInOutCC', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
        animate('.7s', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
        animate('.7s', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
 onToggleSideBar(flag: boolean) {
    this.toggleSideBarFlag = flag;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div [@slideInOutCC] *ngIf="toggleSideBarFlag" class="credit-card-container  {{ submittingPayment ? 'payment-success-container' : ''}}">
        <app-bulk-pay-credit-card [ccTotalDue]="totalDue" [pickupAvailabilityList]='selectedEquipment' (submittingPayment)="isSubmittingPayment(true)"
          (toggleSideBar)="onToggleSideBar(false)" (close)="onCloseBulkPay(false)"></app-bulk-pay-credit-card>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the `LayoutModule` from Angular CDK, then use the `BreakpointObserver` to detect screen size, Here is a working example in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5sb6c5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
        animate('.7s', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
        animate('.7s', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="mobile | async" [@slideInOut] class="obj">
      Test
    </div>
    <div>handset portrait screen size: {{mobile | async}}</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  mobile: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {

    // Observe screen size changes
    this.mobile = breakpointObserver.observe([
      Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait
    ]).pipe(map(res => res.matches));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <h1 #animateMe>{{title}} </h1>
   <button *ngIf="isMobile" (click)="animateMe.classList.add('anim')">Animate</button>`
})
class AppComponent {  
  title = "Hello"
  isMobile = checkmobile() //set to `true` if you want to see it on desktop
}
```

style.css

```
.anim {
  color: red;
  transition: color 500ms;
}
```

checkMobileFunction

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

also here is [pen](https://codepen.io/Chiffie/pen/xyKbMx) demonstrating it and here is original response [how to detect mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/5011810)

*Note: this is minimal code for desired behavior*